# Large object seems to fail in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, 2d

So I am building a 2d rendering engine in JavaScript. the game is ascii art based and all of the layers/sprites are comprised of 2d arrays containing chars. my object hold the `x` and `y` position of each characters corresponding image location.

```js
const charmap1 = {
    ' ':{
        "position": [0, 0],
        "color": 3
    },
    '☺':{
        "position": [0, 1]
    },
    '☻':{
        "position": [0, 2]
    },
    '♡':{
        "position": [0, 3]
    },
    '♦':{
        "position": [0, 4]
    },
    '♣':{
        "position": [0, 5]
    },
    '♤':{
        "position": [0, 6]
    },
    '•':{
        "position": [0, 7]
    },
    '◘':{
        "position": [0, 8]
    },
    '○':{
        "position": [0, 9]
    },
    '◙':{
        "position": [0, 10]
    },
    '♂':{
        "position": [0, 11]
    },
    '♀':{
        "position": [0, 12]
    },
    '♪':{
        "position": [0, 13]
    },
    '♫':{
        "position": [0, 14]
    },
    '☼':{
        "position": [0, 15]
    },


    '►':{
        "position": [1, 0],
        "color": 3
    },
    '◄':{
        "position": [1, 1]
    },
    '↕':{
        "position": [1, 2]
    },
    '‼':{
        "position": [1, 3]
    },
    '¶':{
        "position": [1, 4]
    },
    '§':{
        "position": [1, 5]
    },
    '▬':{
        "position": [1, 6]
    },
    '↨':{
        "position": [1, 7]
    },
    '↑':{
        "position": [1, 8]
    },
    '↓':{
        "position": [1, 9]
    },
    '→':{
        "position": [1, 10]
    },
    '←':{
        "position": [1, 11]
    },
    '∟':{
        "position": [1, 12]
    },
    '↔':{
        "position": [1, 13]
    },
    '▲':{
        "position": [1, 14]
    },
    '▼':{
        "position": [1, 15]
    },

    'space':{
        "position": [2, 0],
        "color": 3
    },
    '!':{
        "position": [2, 1]
    },
    '"':{
        "position": [2, 2]
    },
    '#':{
        "position": [2, 3]
    },
    '$':{
        "position": [2, 4]
    },
    '%':{
        "position": [2, 5]
    },
    '&':{
        "position": [2, 6]
    },
    "'":{
        "position": [2, 7]
    },
    '(':{
        "position": [2, 8]
    },
    ')':{
        "position": [2, 9]
    },
    '*':{
        "position": [2, 10]
    },
    '+':{
        "position": [2, 11]
    },
    ',':{
        "position": [2, 12]
    },
    '-':{
        "position": [2, 13]
    },
    '.':{
        "position": [2, 14]
    },
    '/':{
        "position": [2, 15]
    },


    '0':{
        "position": [3, 0],
        "color": 3
    },
    '1':{
        "position": [3, 1]
    },
    '2':{
        "position": [3, 2]
    },
    '3':{
        "position": [3, 3]
    },
    '4':{
        "position": [3, 4]
    },
    '5':{
        "position": [3, 5]
    },
    '6':{
        "position": [3, 6]
    },
    "7":{
        "position": [3, 7]
    },
    '8':{
        "position": [3, 8]
    },
    '9':{
        "position": [3, 9]
    },
    ':':{
        "position": [3, 10]
    },
    ';':{
        "position": [3, 11]
    },
    '<':{
        "position": [3, 12]
    },
    '=':{
        "position": [3, 13]
    },
    '>':{
        "position": [3, 14]
    },
    '?':{
        "position": [3, 15]
    },

    '@':{
        "position":[4, 0]
    },
    'A':{
        "position:": [4, 1]
    },
    'B':{
        "position:": [4, 2]
    },
    'C':{
        "position:": [4, 3]
    },
    'D':{
        "position:": [4, 4]
    },
    'E':{
        "position:": [4, 5]
    },
    'F':{
        "position:": [4, 6]
    },
    'G':{
        "position:": [4, 7]
    },
    'H':{
        "position:": [4, 8]
    },
    'I':{
        "position:": [4, 9]
    },
    'J':{
        "position:": [4, 10]
    },
    'K':{
        "position:": [4, 11]
    },
    'L':{
        "position:": [4, 12]
    },
    'M':{
        "position:": [4, 13]
    },
    'N':{
        "position:": [4, 14]
    },
    'O':{
        "position:": [4, 15]
    },



    'P':{
        "position:": [5, 0]
    },
    'Q':{
        "position:": [5, 1]
    },
    'R':{
        "position:": [5, 2]
    },
    'S':{
        "position:": [5, 3]
    },
    'T':{
        "position:": [5, 4]
    },
    'U':{
        "position:": [5, 5]
    },
    'V':{
        "position:": [5, 6]
    },
    'W':{
        "position:": [5, 7]
    },
    'X':{
        "position:": [5, 8]
    },
    'Y':{
        "position:": [5, 9]
    },
    'Z':{
        "position:": [5, 10]
    },
    '[':{
        "position:": [5, 11]
    },
    'slash':{
        "position":[5, 12]
    },
    ']':{
        "position":[5, 13]
    },
    '^':{
        "position":[5,14]
    },
    "_":{
        "position":[5, 15]
    },


    'a':{
        "position:": [6, 1]
    },
    'b':{
        "position:": [6, 2]
    },
    'c':{
        "position:": [6, 3]
    },
    'd':{
        "position:": [6, 4]
    },
    'e':{
        "position:": [6, 5]
    },
    'f':{
        "position:": [6, 6]
    },
    'g':{
        "position:": [6, 7]
    },
    'h':{
        "position:": [6, 8]
    },
    'i':{
        "position:": [6, 9]
    },
    'j':{
        "position:": [6, 10]
    },
    'k':{
        "position:": [6, 11]
    },
    'l':{
        "position:": [6, 12]
    },
    'm':{
        "position:": [6, 13]
    },
    'n':{
        "position:": [6, 14]
    },
    'o':{
        "position:": [6, 15]
    },


    'p':{
        "position:": [7, 0]
    },
    'q':{
        "position:": [7, 1]
    },
    'r':{
        "position:": [7, 2]
    },
    's':{
        "position:": [7, 3]
    },
    't':{
        "position:": [7, 4]
    },
    'u':{
        "position:": [7, 5]
    },
    'v':{
        "position:": [7, 6]
    },
    'w':{
        "position:": [7, 7]
    },
    'x':{
        "position:": [7, 8]
    },
    'y':{
        "position:": [7, 9]
    },
    'z':{
        "position:": [7, 10]
    },
    '{':{
        "position:": [7, 11]
    },
    ':':{
        "position":[7, 12]
    },
    '}':{
        "position":[7, 13]
    },
    '~':{
        "position":[7,14]
    },
    "⌂":{
        "position":[7, 15]
    },
    //skipped this part of spritesheet for a sec 


    '░':{
        "position:": [11, 0]
    },
    '▒':{
        "position:": [11, 1]
    },
    '▓':{
        "position:": [11, 2]
    },
    '│':{
        "position:": [11, 3]
    },
    '┤':{
        "position:": [11, 4]
    },
    '╡':{
        "position:": [11, 5]
    },
    '╢':{
        "position:": [11, 6]
    },
    '╖':{
        "position:": [11, 7]
    },
    '╕':{
        "position:": [11, 8]
    },
    '╣':{
        "position:": [11, 9]
    },
    '║':{
        "position:": [11, 10]
    },
    '╗':{
        "position:": [11, 11]
    },
    '╝':{
        "position":[11, 12]
    },
    '╜':{
        "position":[11, 13]
    },
    '╛':{
        "position":[11,14]
    },
    "┐":{
        "position":[11, 15]
    },


    '└':{
        "position:": [12, 0]
    },
    '┴':{
        "position:": [12, 1]
    },
    '┬':{
        "position:": [12, 2]
    },
    '├':{
        "position:": [12, 3]
    },
    '─':{
        "position:": [12, 4]
    },
    '┼':{
        "position:": [12, 5]
    },
    '╞':{
        "position:": [12, 6]
    },
    '╟':{
        "position:": [12, 7]
    },
    '╚':{
        "position:": [12, 8]
    },
    "╔":{
        "position:": [12, 9]
    },
    '╩':{
        "position:": [12, 10]
    },
    '╦':{
        "position:": [12, 11]
    },
    '╠':{
        "position":[12, 12]
    },
    '═':{
        "position":[12, 13]
    },
    '╬':{
        "position":[12,14]
    },
    "╧":{
        "position":[12, 15]
    },

}
```

using this object I then do this

```js
        var scopeX = charmap1[charCode].position[0] * 8
        var scopeY = charmap1[charCode].position[1] * 8

        if(charCode != ' '){
            context.ctx.drawImage(this.colorMap[color], scopeX, scopeY, 7 , 7 , posX, posY, context.fontX, context.fontY);
        }
```

for some unknown reason as soon as charcode `╔` comes through this error occurs `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` occurring when I try to declare scopeX.

the `╔` is clearly in my object every other character works so far. does anybody know whats going on?

Comment: `const charmap1` creates a variable, not an object property. `this.charmap1` should just be `charmap1`.

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain what you are trying to say

Comment: You could try destructuring your position array : `let [scopeX, scopeY] = charmap1[charCode].position`. Then in the `drawImage` method, you multiply the coordinates by 8.

Comment: @NikHendricks what Barmar means is to change `var scopeX = this.charmap1[charCode].position[0] * 8` to `var scopeX = charmap1[charCode].position[0] * 8` - remove the `this`. Same with the next line. And if `colorMap` is a variable (declared with `let`/`const`) then it also doesn't need `this`.

Comment: My entire object is declared as a `const` at the begining of the whole script and i have tried without the `this` (while i was tearing my hair out, in the constructor i made `this.charmap1 = charmap1;` to see if it would do anything) still the same error persists

Comment: This should not be a problem but is there any reason for the mix of double quotes and single quotes in `charmap1`? I point it out just in case you messed up something while editing your code (such as eg. using curly quotes somewhere).